# Why can't I access GAE API in the explorer, but can open them in the browser?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm learning how to create APIs with Google App Engine.

When I try to call a certain method in the explorer, I get the response 404.

[image: Screenshot]

But when I open the very same URL (`http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/quoteapi/v1/quotecollection`) in a browser tab, it works.

[image: Screenshot]

Why?

How can I fix it (make it possible to call these methods work in the explorer) ?

Comment: I'd guess it's because it local to your machine - how can the remote server connect to it? Try deploying your project then trying again with a non-local url.

Answer (score 1):

Did you authorize the request using the toggle button on the right top of the explorer page?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Comment: Right. Sorry if it's the authorization problem. It might return a 403 instead of a 404. I am sorry that I can't get a clue so far that why direct URL works but not explorer. If it is a practicing project. Can you share the codes, maybe through github so that I could recreate the issue and figure out what' s the problem ?